# how to open menu in tablet,when on button click

Tags: android, menu

In my app when I click particular button menu will be open.The code is worked in device,but it is not worked in tablet.The tablet is "XOOM 10 inche,VERSION:4.1.2".I searched a lot in google,but my issue is not solved. Please suggest me how to do this.Is it possible or not?

Comment: please post the code in problem, and logcat output if there's any error.

Comment: not getting any error,when i click button menu is opened in device but when click button in tablet it is not opened